# how pass an array in parameters in volley library

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Have servers template which recives an information

```
['param_id' => 12, 'count' => 4, 'car' => ['mazda 3 bk', '1.6', '2010']]
```

list

```
 list.add(ed_car.getText().toString());
                            list.add(ed_motor.getText().toString());
                            list.add(ed_year.getText().toString());
```

volley passing

```
@Override
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                        Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
                        parameters.put("param_id", id_item);
                        parameters.put("count", spinner_count.getSelectedItem().toString());

                        for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
                        {
                            parameters.put("car",list.get(i));///////???
                        }
                        return parameters;
                    }
```

How correctly pass a list according to their places in the receiving template

Comment: please first check [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question. And most important, this is not a website for seeking a debugging help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    parameters.put("car["+i+"]", list.get(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`parameters.put("car",list.get(i));` will over write the previous values with new one

Solution :

```
   ['mazda 3 bk', '1.6', '2010']
// ^                           ^ json array
```

so create json array and use it's string representation

```
Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<String, String>();
parameters.put("param_id", id_item);
parameters.put("count", spinner_count.getSelectedItem().toString());

JSONArray car = new JSONArray();
for(int i=0; i < list.size(); i++)
{
    car.put(list.get(i));
    // create array and add items into that 
}
parameters.put("car",car.toString());
return parameters;
```

Take look at [toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#toString(int)) which will return the desired format